# Create issue on production but not on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

On my rails application, I am receiving an error on production(heroku) but not on my localhost. All of my migrations are done and I can add it through the console, but I cannot get this to work in the controller.

So the area where the error is occuring is here:

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @registration.save
        EventMailer.new_registration_notification(@registration, @current_event).deliver
        Recipient.create :first_name => @registration.first_name, :last_name => @registration.last_name, :email => @registration.email, :netID => @registration.netID, :event_id => @registration.event_id, :mailing_id => nil
        format.html { redirect_to event_path(@current_event), notice: 'Registration was successful' }
```

Again, I am not getting an error in my development local environment but I am in production. They are both using Postgres. So my registrations ARE saving but Recipient is never created and I get an error. I've checked the heroku logs by running:

```
herkou logs
```

but there are no errors shown. On the front end, you see an error that says "Something went wrong. If you're the application owner please check your logs".

Comment: Actually, more info. I did notice the registration is saving, but the mailer is not sending (using mailgun). This may be the issue...

Comment: add rails_12factor for better log and add error logs...

Comment: Thanks! I solved my issue now but I've been trying to find a solution for better logging so I will check that out!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem, the problem was with sending the mailer. I did not notice that the mailer wasn't sending and just assumed it was an issue creating the Recipient. I needed to fix some configurations in the production.rb file to use the SMTP server. After fixing that the issue went away